# How can I draw dynamic line chart based time and data with Compose in Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A generate continuous datas whom's range is 0 and 100. I hope to draw dynamic line chart based time and data.

The X axis is time (The initial range is 0 and 1 minutes, and it can be increased by time) , and Y axis is data (The range is 0 and 100).

I hope to draw dynamic line chart in the coordinate system.

It's just like Image A.

How can I do? Is there sample code ?

**Code A**

```
private fun soundDbFlow() = flow {
          while (true) {
             val data=(0..100).random().toDouble()
             emit(data)
             delay(100)
          }
}
```

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library for reference in the Android world regarding plotting is MPAndroidCharts.

That is lib is not "jetpack compose compliant" but jetpack compose allows to use good-old android views by using the `AndroidView` composable which you may be able to use with a line chart [as shown in this example](https://medium.com/@leelaprasad4648/creating-linechart-using-mpandroidchart-33632324886d)

```kotlin
AndroidView(factory = { ctx ->  
  com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart(ctx).apply {
    // set properties until it looks like you want it to look like
  }
})
```

Here's [a link to the documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#documentation-notebook_with_decorative_cover) for the MPAndroidCharts lib